# I want to use think time (wait time) IN B/W 2 TRANSACTION CONTROLLER (request)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Constant timer I used but I confused with the execution of contestant timer. there are many request under one TR Controller so If I use contestant timer the given time will apply to all request of TR Controller.

Which Jmeter timer and how I should use to it in the real scenario while execution of jmeter execute.and make sure it should be exclude to the response time.

Pl see the below Image and imagine this is the my scenario.
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below screen shot to use the constant timer for each and every request.

You can use the constant timer for the services which ever you want.

Try this where ever you need to add the think time and execute, it will consider only for the requests(where ever you add that timer).
If you add it to the TR controller it will consider the think time for every request under controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simple one is add a constant timer value 5000 at the level of HTTP Samplers

```
Thread Group
-------------
  >LogIn
  >DashBoard
  >Click On details Link
  >Info Page
```

If above is Your Test plan

then Right click on ThreadGroup-->Add-->Timer-->constant Timer and provide value 5000

In this case the constant timer acts between each http request your are sending

i.e., it sends Login and waits for 5 seconds and it sends Login action and waits for 5 seconds and it sends Dashboard page and waits for 5 seconds and on and on ..
Note : The constant timer element must be sibling to HTTP sampler , but not as a CHILD.

please let me know if you required further info on this .If it helps click answered